# Using Jquery animate for simple css changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do this using .animate instead of .css. When I change it to animate it gets glitchy and won't work

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop != 0) {
    $('#test_box').css({
      "background-color": "red",
      "height": '400px'
    });
  } else {
    $('#test_box').css({
      "background-color": "blue",
      "height": "200px"

    });
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_box" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: Post your code with animate.

Comment: You will need `jQuery-UI` or other library to have a `color animate` effect

Comment: Also you can use `jquery.animate-colors.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For animating effect of increasing the height and decreasing the height of the div use

`transition: height 2s;`

This make the transition smooth.

Here is the working fiddle which might be useful.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoc4bwp6/)

-- Help :)

Answer (score 1):

The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property.  for more reference  check http://api.jquery.com/animate/

it will not change background color.

example:  here only height & width property are changing..

code is updated.. using jquery ui, color also changing...

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop != 0) {
    $('#test_box').animate({
      "background-color": "red",
      "height": '1500px',
      "width": '200px'
    });
  } else {
    $('#test_box').animate({
      "background-color": "blue",
      "height": "700px",
      "width": '500px'

    });
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="test_box" style="height: 900px; width: 200px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: You will need jQuery-UI or other library to have a color animate effect

Answer (score 1):

The following code with `background-color` animation will only work if you include `jQuery-UI` library also(FOR COLOR EFFECT ONLY)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scrollTop != 0) {
        $('#test_box').animate({
          "background-color": "red",
          "height": '400px'
        },500);
      } else {
        $('#test_box').animate({
          "background-color": "blue",
          "height": "200px"

        },500);
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

for make the animation good working, you must increase the high of div.
because `$(window).scrollTop()` will be work if page can scroll.

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wida/4mshLs35/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an additional library to support color animations with jQuery.
This one looks pretty decent:

- http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

For your animation to work smoothly you might want to clear the queue with the `.stop(true, false)` function.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var cssObj = $(window).scrollTop() === 0 ? {
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            height: 200
        } : {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            height: 400
    };

    $('#test_box').stop(true, false).animate(cssObj, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear'
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/c5ch7zf7/)

I must say it's more easy to use CSS transitions as other people mentioned. Simply toggle a css class to give the `#test_box` a state, let's say 'scrolled'.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#test_box').toggleClass('scrolled', $(window).scrollTop() !== 0);
});
```